# WebMVC mapping .jsp Java-Based-Configuration without @ComponentScan

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven

I use Spring's Java-Based-Configuration in my project `hello`.

This is my Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config{
    @Scope("session")
    public A a(){
        return new A();
    }
}
```

This is my `web.xml`

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>world</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>world</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my class `A`

```
@Controller
public class A{
  @RequestMapping("test.html")
  public String foo(){
    return "bar";
  }
}
```

This is my file `bar.jsp`:

```
abc
```

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

Anyway, if i request `http://localhost/hello/test.html` i get a blank page instead of `abc` and the output:

```
DispatcherServlet with name 'world' processing GET request for [/hello/test.html]
Looking up handler method for path /test.html
Did not find handler method for [/test.html]
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hello/test.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'world'
```

Comment: Try with `http://localhost:8080/{alpha}/world/hello/test.html` you have missing the port (8080) and the servlet name `world` and where `{aplha}` must be replaced with the project name if you are working directly with Tomcat or with the **Context Root** if you are working with an IDE, that value can be get it doing the following: Select in the IDE the project -> right click -> properties -> **Web Project Settings**

Comment: My mistake, is not about the `servlet-name`, is about the `url-pattern`, change from `*.html` to **/**

Comment: @ManuelJordan Port 80 is corrent because i get a output in the console. The `url-pattern` is correct too because i get a output in the console. The context-root is correct because i get a output in the console. The url-pattern is correct because i get a output in the console.

Comment: Are you working through your IDE directly? or you have the `.war` file in some Tomcat?

Comment: change from `@RequestMapping("test.html")` to `@RequestMapping("/test.html")`, how you can see add **/**

Comment: why your question has `without @ComponentScan`??? how you are registering the `@Controller` and `@Configuration`?

Comment: @ManuelJordan I realy dont like you to stop here and are impressed by your energy but ... i alredy have solved the question by my own but can accept my very own question just tomorrow! I use `mvn tomcat7:run` (a radical information that has nothing to do with the question) to start the server. `without @ComponentScan` because of a decision my superior has (i argumented using the open-close-principle but no luck). I do not use any IDE.

Comment: And what was the problem and solution?

Comment: Oh I see… the notification is only about new comments, no about new possible solutions added. Good to know all is working fine! Interesting about your boss decision about do not use component scan. For me, it has no sense..

Comment: For me neither, but some decisions are harder like *no IDE*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a `@Bean` at the Config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config{
    @Bean
    @Scope("session")
    public A a(){
        return new A();
    }
}
```

And foo must be like this:

```
public String foo(){
   return "bar.jsp";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments yet so posting this as an answer..

You can include the below snippet in `Config.java` to:

- avoid adding .jsp extension in foo method
- resolve the view without having to add `@Bean` annotation

> ```
> @Bean
> public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
>   UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
>   resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
>   resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
>   resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
>   return resolver;
> }
> ```

**replace the prefix with the path of JSPs in your web application, You can define the view resolver in world-servlet.xml too**